# SQL Server Compatibility level 130 With MD5

Tags: azure-sql-database, sql-server-2016-express

I have read the docs for compatibility level 130 in SQL Server. It's clearly mentioned that MD5 is not supported (deprecated).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level#differences-between-compatibility-level-130-and-level-140

However, I have a computed column making use of MD5 algorithm.

I altered my database from compatibility level 120 - 130.

I inserted a new row in this table and successfully generated the MD5 hash.

It's clearly not breaking...

How can I be assured that my existing MD5 columns won't be the cause of breaking if I move my changes to production?

Comment: Deprecated means a feature may be removed in a future release, but it doesn't remove support.  It just means that ideally you shouldn't use the features in new applications and should prepare to move over to alternatives.  The MD5 hash algorithm is marked as "Features Not Supported in a Future Version of SQL Server" (rather than "Next Version of SQL Server") - which means it will still be in SQL Server 2017.  So in short - avoid MD5 for new applications - and plan on moving to alternatives, but you'll have a few years to do so.